# How to pass id to new user path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

When on the show view of an organization, I can click on an image to go to a new view to create a new member for that organization (association 1:many for organization:members). When clicking the image, I would like to pass the organization_id to the controller so that it is automatically *that* organization for which the new member is created. How to do this?

Included in the members controller:

```
def new
  @organization = Organization.find(params[:id])
  @member = @organization.members.build
def end
```

The link in the organization show view:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("add.png", title: "add"), new_member_path(@organization) %>
```

Now clicking on the link produces the error:

```
Couldn't find Organization with 'id'=
```

So it doesn't seem to pass on the id to the controller. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `new_member_path(id: @organization.id)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the parameter along as :organization_id instead:

```
new_member_path(organization_id: @organization.id)
```

Then change your controller to use the new parameter:

```
@organization = Organization.find(params[:organization_id])
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Is there some rule when you should add such a specification of the type of parameter? I noticed that without the specification `organization_id:` it wouldn't work.

Comment: Using nested resources would do this for you automatically (i.e. you wouldn't have to specify it). So the specification of when it must be specified by hand is if you're not using the nested resources approach. Either approach is equally fine in this case so long as you understand the differences.

Comment: When using resource routes :id is reserved for the resource itself.  In this case that is your Member model.  See the [routing docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) for more details.  As @jefflunt mentioned, you should also consider using nested resources.

Answer (score 0):

By nesting the resources the `id` of the `Organization` can be passed along automatically when you properly format your `new` link.

See [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources). Doing this should create a route something like:

```
new_organization_member GET /organizations/:id/members/new(.format)
```

[@infused's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29925320/249543) is another way to do it.